# Error Creating Many to Many Relationship Using Doctrine 2

Tags: doctrine-orm, zend-framework2

I'm trying to generate the schema for my database using Doctrine 2's ZF2 module but with the following definition:

```
/**
 * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Tag")
 * @ORM\JoinTable(name="Manytomany_Issuetag",
 *      @ORM\joinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="IssueId", referencedColumnName="id")},
 *      @ORM\inverseJoinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="TagId", referencedColumnName="id")}
 *      )
 */
protected $tags;
```

When I run `vendor/bin/doctrine-module orm:schema-tool:update --dump-sql` I receive the following error:

> Annotation @ORM\joinColumns is not allowed to be declared on property Application\Entity\Issue::$tags. You may only use this annotation on these code elements: PROPERTY

**Edit: As requested here is the working annotation**

```
/**
 * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Tag")
 * @ORM\JoinTable(name="Manytomany_Issuetag",
 *      joinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="IssueId", referencedColumnName="id")},
 *      inverseJoinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="TagId", referencedColumnName="id")}
 *      )
 */
 protected $tags;
```

Comment: can you post your working annotation please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need to drop a couple of the `@ORM\` declarations, it should look like this (obviously without my comments)

```
/**
 * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Tag")
 * @ORM\JoinTable(name="Manytomany_Issuetag",
 *      joinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="IssueId", referencedColumnName="id")},
 *     ^ drop the @ORM\
 *      inverseJoinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="TagId", referencedColumnName="id")}
 *     ^ drop the @ORM\
 *      )
 */
protected $tags;
```